# Django-axes is not capturing failed login attempts except in admin site

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

Django-axes isn't working for me in my own views. I can login as many times as I want. Axes still work only with the admin site and I can get user locked. What's the problem?

**urls.py:**

```
from axes.decorators import watch_login
from index import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', watch_login(views.Login)),
    url(r'^$', views.Login),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.Logout),
]
```

**views.py:**

```
def Login(request):
    decyptError = False
    next = request.GET.get('next', '/index/')
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)


    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            ....
            return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Inactive user.")
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
return render(request, "index/login.html", {'redirect_to': next})
```

**settings.py:**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ....
    'axes.middleware.FailedLoginMiddleware',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'axes',
)
```

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?

Comment: I got this somehow working by doing own LoginForm and adding it to login template, but the access attempts logs in admin site doesn't work as should. Still I can get the user locked after too many incorrect login attempts.

Comment: Thanks! Just in case - I checked out the watch_login decorator implementation and figured the reason for my problem. Watch_login expects response code to not be equal to 302 (redirect) and have 'location' header set to mark attempt as

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have right AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS order:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
# AxesStandaloneBackend should be the first backend in the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS list.
'axes.backends.AxesStandaloneBackend',

# Django ModelBackend is the default authentication backend.
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

# Your Custom User Model Backend if exist
'your_app_name.auth_backend.YourCustomAuthBackend',
]
```